# Django: create an object with m2m fields using class based views

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

I'm completely stuck, I want to know the right way to save an object that has m2m fields.

It works with the admin site (not quite right: a field that should be chosen randomly is chosen through a multiplechoicefield but at least the instance is created ) but not the CreateView (nothing happens no object is created)

**models.py**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    #this field is chosen with CheckboxSelectMultiple
    bar = models.ManyToManyField(Bar)
    #this field is supposed to be calculated according to the previous choices 
    baz = models.ManyToManyField(Baz)
```

I tried overriding save method but it did not work .

**forms.py**

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    bar = forms.ModelChoiceField(Bar.objects.all())
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        adding = self.instance._state.adding
        instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if adding:
            instance.baz.add(
                *Baz.objects.filter(bar=instance.bar)
                .values_list('id', flat=True)
                .order_by('?')
            )
        return instance
```

I also tried (commit = False ) and save_m2m().